# Fast Flood Fill

Tags: opengl, graphics, flood-fill

So I have a white picture with a black squiggly line separating the top half from the bottom half. I need to make the bottom half black while keeping the top half white. Pretty simple.

What is the fastest and easiest way to do this? I could just copy all the pixels to RAM, do flood fill and write them back, but I don't feel like it's a good solution.

Is there anything else you can suggest?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't feel like it's a good solution" What are your doubts?

Comment: What is the source of the line? Is it a bitmap, primitives, the output of a shader? Is it animated, controlled by user-input, static?

Comment: @Erno I think it would be unnecessarily slow. Maybe there is some way to do it directly in the video memory?

Comment: @JasonD This line is made of multiple GL_LINEs, and the vertex data is generated by an algorithm that takes a straight line, displaces the midpoint a little bit along the normal, then applies itself recursively to the two resulting segments.

Comment: Can't you turn the squiggly line into a triangulated area so you do not have to fill it with pixels?

Comment: I can, but I've just had another idea, instead of drawing a line every time, I could draw a four-sided polygon (trapezoid) with its top edge being the line and the other edges parallel to the coordinate axes. I think it'll be simpler than triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

How about you modify the picture to be filled in advance below the line? Then, you merely need to draw the picture in the middle of the screen, and then draw a large quad above it in white and one below it in black.

Comment: perhaps because he doesnt always want it to be black? re-useability is always an important factor too, is it more efficient to make a prepared image of every colour you will want or to find a way to pick a colour and fill an area with it?

Comment: That wouldn't actually be a problem, though. Just specify a `glColor` when drawing the image (or do something similar in a shader).